# How to highlight specific rows based on column value in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to give a color to whole row if column value exist in a list, but it is not working, below is the code I'm using:

```py
d = {
  'ids': ['id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4'],
  'values': ['Vanilla', 'Chocolate', 'Butterscotch', 'Strawberry']
}
dd = pd.DataFrame(d)

def highlight(row):
  if row.ids in ['id1', 'id3']:
    return ['background-color: red']
  else:
    return ''

dd.style.apply(highlight, axis=1)
dd.head()
```

I have followed the official docs and several answers on SO, doing the same thing but it is not working. I'm working on google colab though...

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html

Can someone shed some light on this issue?

Comment: change `df['column'] == 'chocolate'`  to `df['ids'].isin(['id1', 'id3'])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a vectorial function:

```
def highlight(row):
    return np.where(row.isin(['id1', 'id3']),
                    'background-color: red', '')

dd.style.apply(highlight)
```

Output:

[image]

##### whole row

```
def highlight(df):
    return np.tile(np.where(df['ids'].isin(['id1', 'id3']), 'background-color: red', '')[:,None],
                   (1, df.shape[1]))

dd.style.apply(highlight, axis=None)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: any way to highlight whole row instead of just 1 column?

Comment: Thank you!! just one thing, the colours doesn't persist when I go to next cell and run `dd` or `dd.head()`, it outputs with normal color, actually, I need to save the df as csv/excel WITH colours...

Comment: You have to chain `style.apply` commands if needed, or with `to_excel`, `style` does **NOT** modify the DataFrame in a persistant way but returns a special object